# URL allows special character in the end. Why?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pimcore

My domain name allows special character (www.testing.com/home/login-) at the end. How do I ensure this is not allowed and show page does not exists cause the right URL is www.testing.com/home/login

```
$routeCustom = new \Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/:controller/:action',
    array(
        'module' => 'website',
        "controller" => "default",
        "action" => "default"
    ),
    array(
        'controller'=>'^[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+', //accept:  a to z , A to Z , - , _ , 0-9 
        'action'=>'^[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+'
    )
);
```

Comment: probably some rewriting or routing going on

Comment: @tim would it be in the .htaccess?

Comment: Many urls (with different appends) can lead to one resource.  This doesn't matter as long as you always pick and publish a canonical one.

Comment: Is this actually coming through to the server, check the output of  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`.

Comment: yes this is actually coming through the sever @Progrock

Comment: So some browsers pass through unsafe characters in URLs.  As said I wouldn't care, as long as you are not publishing these.  People can always append a URL with something like a query string, I don't think it is your responsibility to filter or exclude those URLs.

Comment: If this is specifically a Zend Framework routing issue, include your routes and version.

Comment: If you wanted to outlaw illicit URLs you could probably intercept the request uri before routing and check using something like a regex.  But I'd be very careful if doing so, and personally would avoid.

Comment: @Progrock I have added regex to it. Now the problem is the correct url is www.testing.com/home/login but it allows www.testing.com/home/login-

How do I only allow www.testing.com/home/login

$routeCustom = new \Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/:controller/:action',
    array(
        'module' => 'website',
        "controller" => "default",
        "action" => "default"
    ),
    array(
        'controller'=>'^[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+', //accept:  a to z , A to Z , - , _ , 0-9 
        'action'=>'^[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+'
    )
);

Comment: With your edit you have changed your case to trail with a hyphen - instead of a curly brace.  The hyhen is not deemed an unsafe character like the curly brace.  You can publish a resource with a trailing hyphen, but it would probably be unwise to do so.  Again I do not see why you care. http://example.com/?foo=bar, is a different url to http://example.com/?baz=bat, but likely would lead to the same resource.  As I said before, what matters is that you try and have a one-one match of 'published' links to individual resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how:

```
$routeCustom = new \Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/:controller/:action',
    array(
        'module' => 'website',
        "controller" => "default",
        "action" => "default"
    ),
    array(
        'controller'=>'^[a-zA-Z-_0-9](.*[a-zA-Z0-9])$', //accept:  a to z , A to Z , - , _ , 0-9 
        'action'=>'^[a-zA-Z-_0-9](.*[a-zA-Z0-9])$'
    )
);
```